# How am I able to create bins that follow the shape of the gaussian function?

Tags: python, numpy, linspace

I am very new to coding, and I am trying to create a bell curve Gaussian that creates bars with the bin width 10 and quantity 30. Here us the code I am currently using.

```py
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm 
domain = np.linspace(-2,2,1000)
bins = np.linspace(0, 10, 30)
plt.plot(domain, norm.pdf(domain,0,1), bins)
plt.show()
```

However when I plot them, I get two lines. I now see that it is because I am using np.linspace **but how can I create the bins?**

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to coding you best start with using you defined functions instead of imported modules so *you know what you are doing*

Let's start by defining the Gaussian PDF function:

```
import numpy as np
def gauss(x, mu, sigma, scale):
    return scale*np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*sigma**2))
```

Then define your domain:

```
x = np.arange(start,end,step)
```

Where start and end are the start and the end of your domain and step is your "binsize".
Otherwise you can use:

```
x = np.linspace(start,end,nbins)
```

Which is self explanatory.

Then you can calculate the pdf values using the defined function and plot them

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y = gauss(x,0,1,1)
y2 = gauss(x,0,5,1)
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y,'r',label='Normal PDF')
ax.plot(x,y2,'k',label='Sigma is 5')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: How an I able to set the width of the bins = to say 5?

Comment: The bin size is controlled by the array you feed to the function, you can use x = np.arange(-10,10,5). Mind that theese are not real bins, you are just evaluating a gaussian pdf at various points. If you want to generate data and make an histogram you should use np.hist